# Stripe React Native SDK org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0 issues

Tags: react-native, kotlin, gradle

I'm trying to install the Stripe React Native SDK into a React Native 0.63.4 project, Gradle 6.5, Java 1.8.

However, I receive the below when trying to build the application and cannot figure out where it's going wrong.

I'm trying to build to SDK 33. The project was building successfully prior to the installation of the Stripe SDK via npm.

I've also tried to upgrade Gradle to 7.5 and Java 1.8 / 11. All to no avail.

Just wondering if anyone can provide any help with this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]